# Remove all data from sharedpreference

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I want to clear all data from shared preferences.I tried the below code
but it's not working.What wrong am I doing?

```
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are reading the same preferences file where access them?

Comment: @harism .I am trying to remove all the sharedprefrences for this particular package.Will it not work?

Comment: Show the piece of code how you created your SharedPreference..

Comment: @SumighoshCharuvil why you need how SharedPreferences are created?

Comment: @JordiCastilla i want to know he using PreferenceManager or a Context in creating shared preference

Comment: @SumighoshCharuvil you are right.It's my mistake.I am answering my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This below piece of code helps me.I have to use `PreferenceManager`.

```
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
```

Ah! Simple mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that 'PREFERENCE' is the name of preference that you want to clear.

Comment: that is not what OP is asking... he wants to remove ALL sharedpreferences

Answer (score 0):

You problem is how you get the preferences:

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", 0);
```

You need to get ALL the preferences:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(0);
```

Now, to remove all the SharedPreferences use [Editor.clear()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#clear)

> Mark in the editor to remove all values from the preferences. Once commit is called, the only remaining preferences will be any that you have defined in this editor.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

According documentation:

> Returns a reference to the same Editor object, so you can chain put calls together.

I bet this will work also:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();           
editor.clear().commit();
```

Comment: SharedPreferences.Editor.clear() is showing `non-static method clear() cannot be called from static content`